# "rosbag record -a" in C++?

Tags: ros, c++, rosbag, rosbag-record

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement a node which is able to start recording every topic. It should record everything like the command line `rosbag record -a`. is there a possibility to use that command or something similar in a node which is implemented in c++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216866/%22rosbag-record--a%22-in-c++?/) by [ZOORCK](https://answers.ros.org/users/23735/zoorck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-09-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2015-09-01**:
why not to use rosbag? it is a functional requirement? motivation?

**Comment by [ZOORCK](https://answers.ros.org/users/23735/zoorck/) on 2015-09-01**:
I want to use Rosbag but there are only examples like http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/
but i wanted to record every topic and not single messages.
the reason why i wanted to start that with a node was that it should start in the right moment

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2015-09-01**:
You can call rosbag with parameters from launch file. See question http://answers.ros.org/question/52773/record-with-rosbag-from-launch-file/

**Comment by [ZOORCK](https://answers.ros.org/users/23735/zoorck/) on 2015-09-01**:
thank you
thats a great idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosbag has an API: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API
That is the best way to use it instead of using system commands.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-09-23**:
It looks like it is up to the user to continuously monitor for new topics and subscribe to all of them as they appear, substantially re-implementing `rosbag record -a`.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-09-23**:
Well, that is what he says he wants!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it
i used

#include <stdlib.h>
....
int i;
i=system("rosbag record -a");

maybe there are better solutions but this was the easiest one.
sorry for posting that question.

---

Originally posted by [ZOORCK](https://answers.ros.org/users/23735/zoorck/) with karma: 41 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-11-28**:
how do you stop the recording in cpp?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Copying my answer from http://answers.ros.org/question/10714/start-and-stop-rosbag-within-a-python-script/#219520 (which wasn't really answering it for python, it really belongs here)

The best solution to programmatic rosbag recording I've found is to wrap rosbag::Recorder in a C++ node.  There isn't a way to shutdown recording in Recorder, but there can be a subscriber in the recorder wrapper node which calls ros::shutdown which will cleanly close the current recording bag file, and then the the node can be set to respawn=true.  The exclude list can be passed in as a parameter and then useful other parameters set like below, or have params override defaults as desired:

```
  recorder_options_.exclude_regex = some_string_from_ros_param;
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("exclude list \"" << recorder_options_.exclude_regex << "\"");

  recorder_options_.record_all = true;    
  recorder_options_.trigger = false;
  recorder_options_.regex = false;
  recorder_options_.do_exclude = true;
  recorder_options_.quiet = false;
  recorder_options_.append_date = true;
  recorder_options_.verbose = false;
  recorder_options_.buffer_size = 1048576 * 512;
  recorder_options_.chunk_size = 1024 * 768;
  recorder_options_.limit = 0; // 0 is unlimited
  recorder_options_.split = true;
  recorder_options_.max_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
  recorder_options_.min_space = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
  recorder_options_.min_space_str = "Recording space is running out";
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have implemented a [rosbag record node](https://github.com/epfl-lasa/record_ros) , have a look here if people would be interested in a C++ example.

---

Originally posted by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) with karma: 285 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2